# Which python script is executed if directory path is passed as command line argument to python?

Tags: python, command-line, debian, command-line-arguments

Which script is executed if a directory is passed as argument to python (e.g. if python is called in this way: `$ python3 Domoticz-Google-Assistant/`)?

Best regards,

wewa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute a directory as an argument to python, the file named `__main__.py` will be executed.